# Vintage Power King valuation?

Tags: vintage

I recently got this bike for very cheap... cleaning it up and will sell it since I have no use for it. No idea what to ask for it though.

Anyone know anything about these?

Rear hub is an internal 3 speed hub.

The only markings I see are Power King. Made in Taiwan. On seat-tube I see a "Korvettes Laboratory Approved" sticker.

I'm honestly amazed at how well it is cleaning up. All of the chrome is shining up well, every bearing is still turning smoothly and the shifter and hub even work.

[image: picture]
[image]
[image: picture]
[image: picture]
[image: picture]

Comment: Valuations are totally off topic here, because they're long-term useless.  However the rest of the question is on-topic.

Comment: It looks like a late-model "English racer" similar to what was popular in the 50s and early 60s.  I vaguely recall the "Power King" brand, and am not surprised that Criggie found it to be a store brand.  It appears to be in beautiful condition, though, so it would be good to pass it on to someone who will value it.

Comment: Not what you want to hear having paid for it, but my approximate valuation is 'free to a good home'

Comment: @Criggie “rest of the question is on topic” — I don’t see another part of the valuation question other than “anyone know anything about this” which is too broad.

Comment: So... this question just got edited from "anyone know about these" into valuation question so that it could be closed? This was even more hostile than our usual moderation.

Comment: It's always been a valuation question, the title just reflects that clearly now.  The difference between this one and many others is that the OP was honest enough to state he was looking for a valuation.  I'm not voting to close though because it is an interesting bike, and there is an interesting answer

Comment: @ojs your characterization is completely inaccurate, sorry. Check the edit history: the only changes have been the inclusion of the images, the removal of a "thanks in advance"-type line, the insertion of a hyphen in "seattube", the insertion of a paragraph break and the addition of the word "valuation" to the title, which was always in the body.

Comment: Okay, to be more accurate, a question that included a part about valuation, was otherwise edited to conform site standards but the part about valuation was added to title instead of removing it from question.

Comment: @ojs Well, the alternative would have been to edit that out, leave it as "Anyone know anything about these?" and close as "too broad" or "unclear what you're asking" because there's no objectively answerable question.

Comment: I edited the title to reflect the question as best as I could understand it. I’m not a mod, by the way. You’re also free to edit so that it either better reflects the OP's intent or the site guidelines. I went with the former.

Answer (score 4):

I see a stepthrough frame dating from the 70s or earlier, based on the cottered cranks.

The rims have a dull sheen to them which suggests aluminium alloy not the period steel.  Test with a magnet, and check if the tyres are 27" / -635 size, or have been swapped for a more modern -622 size.

E.J. Korvettes was a department store in the US from 1953 to 1980, and Power King seems to be their house brand.

[image: Advert]

Do a google image search for "korvette bicycle" and browse a lot of results.

Here's a 1978 power king 10speed  http://oldtenspeedgallery.com/owner-submitted/john-hs-1978-e-j-korvette-power-king-10-speed/

---

The contrary point is the "made in taiwan" wording, which implies later than 1970.  Taiwan was only coming into its own as a manufacturer in the 80s.

---

You obviously have a bunch of bikes based on the background.  I'd suggest getting a cane or wicker front basket for the PK and use it as a shopping bike.

None of your other bikes have mudguards - this one has full-length guards and could be ideal as a rain bike with the internal hub and chain guard.

As you've noted, the bearings are working fine 30-40 years later, and it appears to be a great bike.   As they say "the correct number of bicycles to own is **N+1**"